# Pandas parse user agent column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, user-agent

I have a dataframe of http request logs. The only relevant column is the userAgent column which I'm trying to parse. I'm using ua_parser. This turns each userAgent into a nested dictionary like so:

```
>>> from ua_parser import user_agent_parser
>>> user_agent_parser.Parse('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36')
{
     'device': {'brand': None, 
                'model': None, 
                'family': 'Other'}, 
     'os': {'major': '10', 
            'patch_minor': None, 
            'minor': '10', 
            'family': 'Mac OS X', 
            'patch': '5'}, 
     'user_agent': {'major': '55', 
                    'minor': '0', 
                    'family': 'Chrome', 
                    'patch': '2883'}, 
     'string': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'
}
```

I'm trying to create 4 additional columns on my log dataframe using the results of user_agent_parser. I'd like device_brand, device_model, os_family, and user_agent_family columns.

Unfortunately, when I store this as a numpy array, I can't access the dictionary indices:

```
>>> parsed_ua = logs['userAgent'].apply(user_agent_parser.Parse)
>>> logs['device_brand'] = parsed_ua['device']['brand']
KeyError: 'device'
```

I tried converting this to a dataframe so I could merge parsed_ua with logs. Unfortunately, this writes each dictionary to a single column

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(parsed_ua)
userAgent
0   {u'device': {u'brand': None, u'model': None, u...
1   {u'device': {u'brand': None, u'model': None, u...
2   {u'device': {u'brand': None, u'model': None, u...
3   {u'device': {u'brand': None, u'model': None, u...
4   {u'device': {u'brand': None, u'model': None, u...
```

How can I parse the userAgent column and write the results to multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) method:

```
In [146]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(parsed_ua)
Out[146]:
  device.brand device.family device.model os.family os.major os.minor  \
0         None         Other         None  Mac OS X       10       10

  os.patch os.patch_minor                                   string  \
0        5           None  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS...

  user_agent.family user_agent.major user_agent.minor user_agent.patch
0            Chrome               55                0             2883
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you've done, you can use lambda of [Series' apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
ua = logs['userAgent'].apply(lambda ua: user_agent_parser.Parse(ua))

logs['device_brand'] = ua.apply(lambda x: x['device']['brand'])
logs['device_model'] = ua.apply(lambda x: x['device']['model'])
logs['os_family'] = ua.apply(lambda x: x['os']['family'])
logs['user_agent_family'] = ua.apply(lambda x: x['user_agent']['family'])
```

Comment: That's a lot less round about. Thank you!