# Parsing User Agent in R but how to do with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the string,i need to parse Agent with information like below :

my date looks like :`"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"`

and output like data table which contains the information in columns.

in R tried with package :

```
library(uaparserjs)
library(dplyr)
dplyr::glimpse(ua_parse(mydata))%>%data.frame()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Observations: 1
Variables: 7
$ userAgent     <chr> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safa...
$ ua.family     <chr> "Chrome"
$ ua.major      <chr> "67"
$ ua.minor      <chr> "0"
$ ua.patch      <chr> "3396"
$ os.family     <chr> "Linux"
$ device.family <chr> "Other"
```

**Any best package suggest with PYTHON ?**

Comment: So is the R output the desired output? And where is the Python code you tried so far?

Comment: i am new to the python and dont know still which packages are to be used

Comment: in r output with 5 columns only but expecting some more information ..so is there any better methods in python?

Comment: So for every software you want the version number and the additional info in brackets nicely formatted?

Comment: yes and i have gone through with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840862/pandas-parse-user-agent-column-into-multiple-columns but partial information only i got

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/user-agent-parser ...this one is good

Comment: Your problem is, that this does not list all software?

Comment: exactly sir.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183563/discussion-between-user8408080-and-sai-saran).

Comment: superb ..thank u for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you all software with version and additional info if provided:

```
import re

string = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"

software = re.findall(r"\w+/[\d\.]+\.? \(.+?\)|\w+/[\d\.]+\.?", string)

info = {}
for i in software:
    version=re.search(r"(?<=/)[\d+\.]+\,?", i).group()
    try:
        additional_info = re.search(r"(\(.+?\))", i).group()
    except:
        additional_info = ""
    info[re.search(r"\w+(?=/)",i).group()] = {"version":version, "additional_info":additional_info}
```

The first regex finds all the software and then I create a dictionary with the structure `{"software1" : {"version" : version, "additional_info" : additional_info}, "software2" :....}`